# Macro on internet explorer working fine with f8 but with f5 popping up a mismatch error

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a macro which open internet explorer, login on site and then work on that. Macro is working fine till login and shows error at "MON". There are some other issues:

1. Macro is working fine while debugging (using f8) but when run it with F5 an error gets pop up "type mismatch error 13" for "MON". Can someone please suggest what would be the reason for this?
2. While defining Mon what definition would be perfect to use?
3. Is there any other way of selecting from the drop down list on the Internet explorer.
4. It would be of great help if anyone can provide the code for switching to opened Internet Explorer without using shell.

We have also used extra waiting time too like "1 min" but the issue still exist.

```
Sub Intex()
    Set ie = Createobject("internetexplorer.application")  
    ie.visible = ture
    ie.navigate Range("URL").Value

    Application.wait(now + timevalue("00:00:15"))
    Set Login_Id = ie.document.getelementbyid("LoginID")
    Login_id.value = ****
    Set Login_pass = ie.document.getelementbyid("Password")
    Login_pass.value = ****  
    ie.document.form(0). submit
    Application.wait(now + timevalue("00:00:15"))

    Set Mon= ie.document.getelementbyid("ddlReportingMonth")

    For i= 0 to Mon.options.length
       If Mon.Options(i).Text = Range("Rep_Mon").value
            Mon.selectindex = i
            Exit For
       End If

    Next i
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure the Macro is working fine? I'm asking because `If Mon.Options(i).Text = Range("Rep_Mon").value` is missing a `Then` Statement after if condition and is bound to produce an error. So I wonder, if you really did debug it as you claimed

Comment: Yes i have added "Then" there. It's just i missed while typing here

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting a set amount of time for the page to load

```
Application.wait(now + timevalue("00:00:15"))
```

try using the following lines:

```
Do While ie.busy
Loop
```

that should help with your error when trying to set the Mon variable

Comment: Yes, we tried this too but when we running with this code it did not wait for page to get proper loaded that's why we use wait time instead of this